# Including Pchart with mouse over inside the kohana frame work

Tags: php

I was using pchart to draw the graph in kohana , the problem i am facing is when i tried to include the mouse over for the pchart i was getting empty page.but pchart with the mouse over is working in normal php.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue,

Solution:

Previously i placed the pchart mouseover js files inside the system/vendor folder and tried to access it thats y i was not able to get.

Now i placed the pchart mouseover js inside the js folder in the root and changed the tmp path inside the pchart class to the exact path.Now mouse over works.